Where did the tradition of reading a passage from Psalm 90:17 come from before Psalm 91?
I often see in siddurs that before Psalm 91 they read the passage 90:17 (Vihi Noam). Where did this custom come from? Is it from Ari? Is this somehow connected with Kabbalah?
